# build Custom post type and make it child for Posts and put it as comment

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to build custom post type under name "lesson"

I try tis code

```
 function my_register_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Lessons', 'Post Type General Name', '1fix' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Lesson', 'Post Type Singular Name', '1fix' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Lessons', '1fix' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Lessons', '1fix' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Lesson', '1fix' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'lesson', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_cpt' );

function my_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'lesson-parent', 'post', 'lesson_attributes_meta_box', 'lesson', 'side', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_boxes' );

function lesson_attributes_meta_box( $post ) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    $pages = wp_dropdown_pages( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __( '(no parent)' ), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0 ) );
    if ( ! empty( $pages ) ) {
        echo $pages;
    }
}

function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%lesson%', '([^/]+)', 'lesson=');
    add_permastruct('lesson', '/lesson/%postname%/%lesson%', false);
    add_rewrite_rule('^lesson/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?lesson=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );

function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'lesson' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;

    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_post = get_post( $parent );

    $permalink = str_replace('%postname%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

but when I add new lesson, I can't choose Parent post
[image]

is there ant bug in this code?

and is there possibilities to put my custom post type as comments?

Comment: I guess `wp_dropdown_pages()` works with hierarchical post types. "post" post type is not hierarchical.

Comment: @anton it shows me pages not posts

Comment: You set `'post_type' => 'post'` which is not hierarchical post type. How can it show you pages with this attribute? I checked on my localhost and it works with default 'pages' post type which is hierarchical and other custom post types with hierarchical structure. But shows nothing with "post" post type.

Comment: @anton I want my custom post type to be child for a post not a page
when I use wp_dropdown_pages()  it makes pages as parents not post

Comment: I understand your request, but i'm telling you why you see an empty metabox. Because "post" post type is not hierarchical.  I never done this before, but you can try to make default "post" post type hierarchical. Check answers from this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750931/wordpress-how-to-add-hierarchy-to-posts

Comment: yeah I find one.. thank you

Comment: Does wp_dropdown_pages() shows posts from "post" post type right now?

Comment: @anton no I used code that allow Post type -> 'post be hierarchical... its from the link